# Terminated by user. Copying file fatally failed. Copying files to remote side failed

Tags: winscp, winscp-net

My .net app based on winscp stopped working. While uploading a bigger file, I get

```
WinSCP.SessionRemoteException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Nachricht = Terminated by user.
Copying file 'test.mp4' fatally failed.
Copying files to remote side failed.
  Quelle = WinSCPnet
  Stapelüberwachung:
   bei WinSCP.OperationResultBase.Check()
   bei Hochladen.Form1.hochladenscp(String file) in Form1.cs: Zeile81
   bei Hochladen.Form1.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<werfen>b__0() in Form1.cs: Zeile175
   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   bei System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   bei System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

And it is pointing to `transferResult.Check();`, saying

```
WinSCP.SessionRemoteException: Terminated by user.
Copying file 'test.mp4' fatally failed.
Copying files to remote side failed.
```

Scp exists on the server, just like before, the scp password is right, just like the ssh-key.

Here the end of the logs

```
. 2018-10-19 13:00:37.119 Binary transfer mode selected.
> 2018-10-19 13:00:37.120 T1539559055 0 1539946831 0
. 2018-10-19 13:00:37.151 SCP remote side confirmation (0)
> 2018-10-19 13:00:37.151 C0644 1487483772 WeitWeg.mp4
. 2018-10-19 13:00:37.195 SCP remote side confirmation (0)
. 2018-10-19 13:00:37.195 Sending BINARY data (first block, 32768 bytes)
. 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 Waiting for dispatching send buffer timed out, asking user what to do.
. 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 Asking user:
. 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 **Host is not communicating for 15 seconds.
. 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 
. 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 Wait for another 15 seconds?** ()
< 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 Script: Host is not communicating for more than 15 seconds.
< 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 Still waiting...
< 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 Note: If the problem repeats, try turning off 'Optimize connection buffer size'.
< 2018-10-19 13:01:06.560 Warning: Aborting this operation will close connection!
. 2018-10-19 13:02:06.162 Attempt to close connection due to fatal exception:
* 2018-10-19 13:02:06.162 **Terminated by user.**
. 2018-10-19 13:02:06.162 Closing connection.
. 2018-10-19 13:02:06.162 Sending special code: 12
. 2018-10-19 13:02:06.162 Sent EOF message
< 2018-10-19 13:02:06.166 Script: Terminated by user.
< 2018-10-19 13:02:06.166 Copying file 'test.mp4' fatally failed.

< 2018-10-19 13:02:06.166 Copying files to remote side failed.
```

What could be the solution?

Comment: Log file please (`Session.SessionLogPath`).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl There you go: https://pastebin.com/5CEU1tA5

Comment: The log link does not work. Though from the error message, I guess that your are using SCP protocol. Why? Did you try SFTP?

Comment: Your duplicate post on WinSCP forum: https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=26879

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Is scp not safer than sftp?

Comment: Both run over SSH, so both are equally safe.

Comment: I solved it by using resume and setting SendBuf to 0.